# Best practices for client presentation when not face to face

Tags: business, client-relations, presentation

When presenting a project to a client, I like to walk them through stages. This helps me limit their perception to a specific path of design and tends to go a long way to helping them understand aspects of the project that they may overlook otherwise.

When presenting design roughs or mock-ups via email or via links to web pages a problem arises. The client doesn't stay where I want them. They will often click ahead or view things I don't yet want them to view.

In a face to face meeting I control when a client sees something. However, it's not feasible through electronic communication to send a link or PDF, then discuss, then send another link or PDF and discuss.

Phone conversations are not workable, they would still require a PDF or links.

If mock-ups or roughs are set on a web page you can create a link path through various pages, but there's no guarantee a client won't click ahead too fast or just click ahead before you get a chance to discuss anything.

So.. my question....

When a face to face meeting is not possible and you are working on a project that is, let's say, a logo... **How do you ensure the client views items in the order you *want* them to view things and which allows you to discuss iterations down the path you want?**

Are there any best practices for this?

**Edit to add**
.... And if online meeting software installation is not an option?
<sub>although current answers regarding meeting software **are** valid answers. Just wanted to open this up a bit more if possible.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a chatterbox. I leave notes. Stickies, arrows, numbered captions. Or I would lay out the logos in InDesign and have copy explaining everything alongside, as if it were a transcript of me talking to them face-to-face.

I'd also probably have instructions: "Please read through the document in page order, as this will help you to understand the progression of the project." Sort of inviting or encouraging the client to do the right thing rather than leap ahead willy-nilly.

Answer (score 10):

Simple.  Have a webinar or a remote session from your desktop.  Take the same time out as you would in a meeting but with a webinar you control what is shown, done, and the path the discussion should take.  If that doesn't work then code the site to only allow certain access or change the links to not follow through.

Some options:

- [GoToWebinar](http://www.gotomeeting.com/online/webinar)
- [Webex](http://www.webex.com/webinars/)
- [Anymeeting](https://www.anymeeting.com/)
- [Join Me (logmein)](https://www.join.me/offers/signup/1/?wt.srch=1&utpk=free%20webinar&originid=348436&mcomb=sCarqasGv%7C64118514666%7Cfree%20webinar%7Cp%7Ci8rbbhb5l0%7Cc&gclid=CO29mYyksMUCFQuraQod5isAaw)

Comment: Another option: https://www.teamviewer.com/es/ You can complement this with a phone call.

Comment: @Rafael TeamViewer supports VoIP, but has the microphone muted by default. Just a matter of pressing a button, and no phone is necessary!

Comment: Skype and Google Hangouts work great too.

Comment: @Kroltan, Oh, never stop learning new things :o)

Comment: Akype d Hangouts tend to compress screencasts to maintain frames per second, while TeamViewer lowers framerate with the same quality. Depending on usage, you may prefer resolution or fluidity

Answer (score 4):

If you want something where neither you or your client have to install a piece of software I would recommend you just use Google Hangouts. Then you can share your screen as you navigate your presentation at the pace you want. And, you don't need a Google+ account to use it.

Answer (score 3):

If an in-person or online meeting is not possible then I'd suggest using an annotated PDF full of your designer notes - the equivalent of providing a marked up document.

The only downside to this approach would be if you need to show complex motion/interactive designs in which a PDF does not really supply frame-by-frame annotation capabilities. I guess for complex motion and interactive designs you could provide a "designers" audio track or even a designer's captioning track to provide information in-sync with the motion/interaction design.

Another possibility - a screen capture video (using Camtasia, Quicktime, or something similar) of you demoing and narrating your design work.